# Clicked Item not playing song and giving error `The system cannot find the file specified'

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to play a song from my listview in UWP.  However when I click on the song (listview item) to play it I get the follwing error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)'
```

This is my code:

```
private async Task InitFolderAsync()
    {
        StorageFolder musicLib = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
        var files = await musicLib.GetFilesAsync();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            StorageItemThumbnail currentThumb = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.MusicView, 50, ThumbnailOptions.UseCurrentScale);
            var albumCover = new BitmapImage();
            albumCover.SetSource(currentThumb);

            var musicProperties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
            var musicname = musicProperties.Title;
            var musicdur = musicProperties.Duration;

            var artist = musicProperties.Artist;
            if (artist == "")
            {
                artist = "Unknown";
            }

            var album = musicProperties.Album;
            if (album == "")
            {
                album = "Unknown";
            }
            MusicList.Add(new MusicLib
            {
                FileName = musicname,
                Artist = artist,
                Album = album,
                Duration = musicdur,
                AlbumCover = albumCover,
                MusicPath = file.Path
            });

        }
    }

    private async void SongClicked(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var file = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync(e.ClickedItem.ToString());

        if (file != null)
        {
            var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
            mediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
            mediaElement.Play();
        }

    }

    private async void objMediaPlayer_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // If the end of the ListView is reached and the last song was played stop.
        if ((AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex + 1) == AudioFilesLV.Items.Count)
        {
            mediaElement.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            // This line you should try to change. When the last song was not played 
            //-> select next one and play them.
            AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex = AudioFilesLV.SelectedIndex + 1;
            var file = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync(AudioFilesLV.SelectedItem.ToString());
            if (file != null)
            {
                var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
                mediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
                mediaElement.Play();
            }
        }
    }
```

So basically after you click on the song to play it should then automatically go to the next song and play it.  I haven't got to that stage yet as it does not want to play the song I clicked.

Thanks

Comment: Did you checked what the actual value of `e.ClickedItem` is?

Comment: @MatJ I realized that I need to do that but am not sure of how to do that.

Comment: Hello, you can add break point before the corresponding line of code (`var file = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync(e.ClickedItem.ToString());`), check its actual value when debugging (move the cursor to `e.ClickedItem` to view)

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast `e.ClickedItem` to a `MusicLib` and then pass its `MusicPath` to the `GetFileAsync` method:

```
private async void SongClicked(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var clickedItem = e.ClickedItem as MusicLib;
    if (clickedItem != null)
    {
        var file = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync(clickedItem.MusicPath);
        if (file != null)
        {
            var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
            mediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
            mediaElement.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.  Still not working though getting error  `cannot convert from 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo' to 'string`  by  `var file = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFileAsync(clickedItem.MusicPath);`

Comment: Are you saying that the `MusicPath` property of your `MusicLib` returns something else than a string?